# Significato di "vantare altri numeri" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Idrogeno* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> L'obiezione mi giunse offensiva: come si permetteva Enrico di dubitare di una mia affermazione? Io ero il teorico, solo io: lui, benché titolare (in certa misura, e poi solo per «transfert») del laboratorio, anzi, appunto perché non era in condizione di **vantare altri numeri**, avrebbe dovuto astenersi dalle critiche.

Ho cercato alla voce "vantare" di parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "vantare altri numeri" riferita a Enrico che appare nel testo: di che cosa non si poteva vantare?

Per capire il contesto, Enrico e l'io narrante avevano sedici anni ed erano amici che sognavano di diventare chimici nel futuro. Riguardo al laboratorio menzionato nel brano, il racconto spiega:

> Il fratello di Enrico, misterioso e collerico personaggio di cui Enrico non parlava volentieri, era studente in chimica, e aveva installato un laboratorio in fondo a un cortile, in un curioso vicolo stretto e storto che si diparte da piazza della Crocetta, e spicca nella ossessiva geometria torinese come un organo rudimentale intrappolato nella struttura evoluta di un mammifero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qui **numero** è usato nel senso metaforico di *qualità necessarie* o *competenze*.

Vedi la definizione del [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/numero/) (7. Locuz. particolari):

> Forse con riferimento a qualche gioco: *avere tutti i n.*, tutte le qualità necessarie al successo; *un giovane che ha dei n.*, doti positive e buone possibilità di riuscita

La frase **[non poter] vantare altri numeri** assume appunto il significato di non poter vantare competenze per contraddire l'altro personaggio.